# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset в php7

Tags: php, массивы, php7

Есть функция, параметры которой задаются через массив и внутри с ними произвожу определенные вычисления, где мне нужны манипуляции с числами.

```
function comment_html($likes=array('minus' =>0,'plus'=>0 )){
    if(!$likes['plus'])$likes['plus']=0; // Illegal string offset
    if(!$likes['minus'])$likes['minus']=0; // in home..
    ...
}
```

Все работало хорошо до тех пор пока не обновил до `php7`. 
Теперь получаю регулярные варинги:

> PHP7 Warning: Illegal string offset

Понимаю, что это связано с приведением значений массива к числовым значениям, но, не понимаю как это исправить..

**UDP:** как мне подсказали в комментариях, реально ошибка не в строках выше, а в данных, которые я оправляю в функцию. 
Вот такие значения могут быть на входе:

```
string(0) "" 
string(1) "1" 
string(0) "" 
array(2) { ["plus"]=> int(1) ["minus"]=> int(1) } 
array(1) { ["plus"]=> int(1) }
string(1) "2"
array(2) { ["plus"]=> string(1) "0" ["minus"]=> int(1) }
array(2) { ["plus"]=> string(1) "1" ["minus"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

И затем отправляю в конструкторе
`$comment = $this->comment_html($likes);`

Как можно унифицировать эти значения, чтобы варинга не возникало и все работало верно, как и раньше?

**UDP2:** С массивами все понятно, а вот с преобразованием `string` в `array` у меня не выходит

```
if(isset($likes) === true && $likes === '') {
   var_dump($likes); //string(0) ""
   $likes=array('minus' =>0,'plus'=>0 ); //в месте нулей ничего не выводит
   if(!$likes['plus'])$likes['plus']=0; //работает, выводит 0 с варингом
   if(!$likes['minus'])$likes['minus']=0; //работает, выводит 0 с варингом
}
```

Comment: думаю, что проблема не с этим кодом, а с тем массивом, который вы передаете функции. С какого-то момента в этом массиве не оказалось ключа `plus`...

Comment: php7 ну укажите явно, что должен прилетать массив. И будете получать ошибку и знать, что вы прислали строку вместо массива и вопросов не будет возникать.

Comment: @splash58 не понял вас, есть же дефолтные значения ключей `$likes=array('minus' =>0,'plus'=>0 )` или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @binliz "php7 ну укажите явно, что должен прилетать массив."
что и куда указать?

А здесь вообще ничего не понял
"И будете получать ошибку и знать, что вы прислали строку вместо массива и вопросов не будет возникать."
Зачем мне получать ошибку и делать код нерабочим вместо варинга?

Comment: Вам не намекнули  а прямо сказали и не только я. Что данные которые вы передаете это не массив, в этом проблема. Проверяйте всегда входные данные.

Comment: @Вася если вы вызовите функцию вот так - func([]), подставлять дефолтные ключи никто не будет, а если func(), подставися дефолтный массив

Comment: function comment_html(array $likes = ['minus' =>0,'plus'=>0]){ вот так! или уже конкретно в вашей функции первой же строкой is_array($likes)

Comment: Сделайте проверку [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-array.php) - `if(!is_array($likes)){exit('Увы, но вы ошиблись и передали не массив, а тип: '.gettype($likes));}` и посмотрите в чем беда =)))

Comment: @splash58 - дополнил вопрос. Есть идеи как нужно подправить

Comment: Если приходит строка, куда ее девать предполагается - в плюсы?

Comment: @splash58 или в плюсы или в минусы в зависимости от параметра

Comment: `isset($likes) === true` не нужно так делать. Это бессмысленно, конструкция `isset`возвращает и так `bool`. а вот это `$likes === ''` не пропустит `null`, и могут случиться проблемы. лучше сделать `!$likes` либо `empty($likes)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если форматы данных на входе ограничены списком из вопрос, вот так можно

```
$template = ['minus' =>0,'plus'=>0];
if(is_array($likes)) {
    $likes = array_replace($template, $likes);
}
else {
    $likes = ['minus' =>0,'plus'=> $likes];
}
```

Comment: с альтернативным условием проблема. Если приходит одиночный $likes ['minus'] со значением, то он обнуляется

Comment: посмотрите - всё отлично, может надо добавить конвертацию в целые из строк - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d244cc285b64c613ab3fce46b4e4b3a0a89c4a2

Comment: а почему вы изначально задаете тестовые данные как массив?
там они именно идут как частично строковые, так и как массив, поэтому и результат разный

Comment: В функцию же я отдаю все ваши образцы по очереди и массивы и строки

Comment: я не знаю по какой причине, но после этих дополнений (о отличие от первоначального) зануляются везде минус лайки. 
К примеру, вместо цифр 1,2,3 напротив минусов выводятся везде 0, хотя до условия из базы все подтягивается верно

Comment: я даже не знаю, что вам сказать. Вы ходили по ссылке? Добавьте там вариантов входных данных, гляньте, в каком случае не так получается. Поставьте отладочную печать в своей функции, выведите входные данные и получившийся массив. приведите пример, когда получается неправильно. Попробуем  поправить

Comment: да, конечно ходил, но мне это не дает понимания проблемы.
У меня проблема с преобразованием стринга в массив, обновил вопрос в `UPD2` пояснил на примере, что именно у меня не получается: там я проверяю то, что не массив и с ним хочу сделать необходимые преобразования

Comment: разобрался я в вопросе. Оказывается, когда я выводил значение `$likes['minus']="0";` как строковое в скобках и помещал внутри  `<?php <input value="'.$minus.'"> ?>`, то кавычки дублировались `<input value=""0"">` и я никак не мог получить нужного значения...